# Compare an array string with a string

Tags: php, arrays, string, curl, http-status-codes

i am finishing a project, but i need to compare if a HTTP Status Code is the same as another. I have a big algorithm and i reduced them and i identified the problem:
I have an array called "$file_headers", and in the ["Status"] position saves "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently", and in the if clause i compare to "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" (which obviously is the same), but my code doesn't say the same as me. I detect the HTTP Status Code using cURL. My PHP code is the following:

```
<?php
// create curl resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "fb.com");

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//enable headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
//get only headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

$data = explode("\n",$output);
$headers_one = $data;
$headers_two = array();

$headers_two['Status'] = $data[0];
array_shift($data);
foreach($data as $part){
    $middle = explode(":",$part);

    $msg = null;
    if(sizeof($middle) > 2){
      if(strpos($middle[0],"Location") === false){   
          for($i = 1; $i <= sizeof($middle)-1;$i++){
            $msg .= $middle[$i];
          }
      } else {
          for($i = 1; $i <= sizeof($middle)-1;$i++){
            if($i == 1){
                $msg .= $middle[$i] . ":";
            } else {
                $msg .= $middle[$i];
            }
          } 
      }    
    } else if(isset($middle[1])){
      $msg = $middle[1];
    }
    $headers_two[trim($middle[0])] = trim($msg);
}

array_pop($headers_one);
array_pop($headers_one);
array_pop($headers_two);

$file_headers = $headers_two;
if($file_headers["Status"] === ("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently") || $file_headers["Status"] === ("HTTP/1.1 301")){
  echo "OK!";
} else {
  echo "NO!";
}

//print all headers as array
/*echo "<pre>";
print_r($headers_one);
echo "</pre><br />";*/
echo "<pre>";
echo $file_headers["Status"];
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

If anyone can help me i would appreciate it. THANKS AND HAVE A NICE DAY DEV!

Comment: why you added extra `parenthesis` on the string like `("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently")` and `("HTTP/1.1 301")` , keep in mind you are comparing with `===` not `==`?

Comment: Being Sunny, i forgot to erase it in my simplified algorithm, but in my original code is something like this: ("HTTP/" . $HTTPversions[$y] . " " . $StatusURL[$x]->code . " " . $StatusURL[$x]->name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$headers_two['Status']` is the only element you're not `trim()`ing, so it has some whitespace around it, which makes the comparison fail. Do it like this:

```
$headers_two['Status'] = trim($data[0]);
```

And it'll work just fine.